# Bootstrap prediction interval

Tags: bootstrap, prediction-interval

Is there any bootstrap technique available to compute prediction intervals for point predictions obtained e.g. from linear regression or other regression method (k-nearest neighbour, regression trees etc.)?

Somehow I feel that the sometimes proposed way to just bootsrap the point prediction (see e.g. [Prediction intervals for kNN regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162249/prediction-intervals-for-knn-regression)) is not providing a prediction interval but a confidence interval.

An example in R

```
# STEP 1: GENERATE DATA

set.seed(34345)

n <- 100 
x <- runif(n)
y <- 1 + 0.2*x + rnorm(n)
data <- data.frame(x, y)


# STEP 2: COMPUTE CLASSIC 95%-PREDICTION INTERVAL
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
plot(fit) # not shown but looks fine with respect to all relevant aspects

# Classic prediction interval based on standard error of forecast
predict(fit, list(x = 0.1), interval = "p")
# -0.6588168 3.093755

# Classic confidence interval based on standard error of estimation
predict(fit, list(x = 0.1), interval = "c")
# 0.893388 1.54155


# STEP 3: NOW BY BOOTSTRAP
B <- 1000
pred <- numeric(B)
for (i in 1:B) {
  boot <- sample(n, n, replace = TRUE)
  fit.b <- lm(y ~ x, data = data[boot,])
  pred[i] <- predict(fit.b, list(x = 0.1))
}
quantile(pred, c(0.025, 0.975))
# 0.8699302 1.5399179
```

Obviously, the 95% basic bootstrap interval matches the 95% confidence interval, not the 95% prediction interval. So my question: How to do it properly?

Comment: At least in the case of ordinary least squares, you'll need more than just point predictions; you want to use the estimated residual error in order to construct prediction intervals, too.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44860

Comment: @duplo: thank you for pointing this out. The correct length of the classic prediction intervals is relying directly on normality assumption of the error term, so if it is too optimistic, then quite certainly also the bootstrapped version will be if it is derived from there. I wonder if there is in general bootstrap method working in regression (not necessarily OLS).

Comment: I think \textit{conformal inference} could be what you want, which lets you construct resampling-based prediction intervals that have valid finite sample coverage, and do not over-cover too much. There is a good paper which is available at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04173.pdf, which is possible to read as an introduction to the topic, and an R package that is available from https://github.com/ryantibs/conformal.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on how to do this using the tidymodels interface: https://www.bryanshalloway.com/2021/04/05/simulating-prediction-intervals/ (I also link to a blog post that uses a python approach).

Comment: @Bryan: thanks! Very good hint. Do you think the procedure works well when the individual uncertainty strongly depends on the prediction (like when you fit a linear regression in a funnel shaped scatter)?

Comment: @Michael , no, it would not do well in those cases (or cases of heteroskedasticity generally). It is still assuming the variance in the sample is roughly iid. Here's a gist showing the results when trying it on such a dataset: https://gist.github.com/brshallo/a9e5d245feae3dfc551a122516a702ff

I +1'd Simon's comment above about conformal inference as a place to check. Also see my follow-up post (linked to above) that goes through an example with quantile regression (which would work better when errors are not iid.

Comment: *the error in the sample is roughly iid

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot also for the example demonstrating the issue with heteroscedastic errors.

Answer (score 39):

The method laid out below is the one
described in Section 6.3.3 of Davidson and Hinckley (1997),
*Bootstrap Methods and Their Application*.  Thanks to Glen_b and his
comment [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44860/how-to-prediction-intervals-for-linear-regression-via-bootstrapping#comment87119_44860).  Given that there were several questions on Cross Validated on this topic, I thought it was worth writing up.

The linear regression model is:
\begin{align}
Y_i &= X_i\beta+\epsilon_i
\end{align}

We have data, $i=1,2,\ldots,N$, which we use to estimate the $\beta$ as:
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}} &= \left( X'X \right)^{-1}X'Y
\end{align}

Now, we want to predict what $Y$ will be for a new data point, given that we know $X$ for it.  This is the prediction problem.  Let's call the new $X$ (which we know) $X_{N+1}$ and the new $Y$ (which we would like to predict), $Y_{N+1}$.  The usual prediction (if we are assuming that the $\epsilon_i$ are iid and uncorrelated with $X$) is:
\begin{align}
Y^p_{N+1} &= X_{N+1}\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}}
\end{align}

The forecast error made by this prediction is:
\begin{align}
e^p_{N+1} &= Y_{N+1}-Y^p_{N+1}
\end{align}

We can re-write this equation like:
\begin{align}
Y_{N+1} &= Y^p_{N+1} + e^p_{N+1}
\end{align}

Now, $Y^p_{N+1}$ we have already calculated.  So, if we want to bound $Y_{N+1}$ in an interval, say, 90% of the time, all we need to do is estimate consistently the $5^{th}$ and $95^{th}$ percentiles/quantiles of $e^p_{N+1}$, call them $e^5,e^{95}$, and the prediction interval will be $\left[Y^p_{N+1}+e^5,Y^p_{N+1}+e^{95} \right]$.

How to estimate the quantiles/percentiles of $e^p_{N+1}$?  Well, we can write:
\begin{align}
e^p_{N+1} &= Y_{N+1}-Y^p_{N+1}\\
          &= X_{N+1}\beta + \epsilon_{N+1} - X_{N+1}\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}}\\
          &= X_{N+1}\left( \beta-\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}} \right) + \epsilon_{N+1}
\end{align}

The strategy will be to sample (in a bootstrap kind of way) many times from $e^p_{N+1}$ and then calculate percentiles in the usual way.  So, maybe we will sample 10,000 times from $e^p_{N+1}$, and then estimate the $5^{th}$ and $95^{th}$ percentiles as the $500^{th}$ and $9,500^{th}$ smallest members of the sample.

To draw on $X_{N+1}\left( \beta-\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}} \right)$, we can bootstrap errors (cases would be fine, too, but we are assuming iid errors anyway).  So, on each bootstrap replication, you draw $N$ times with replacement from the variance-adjusted residuals (see next para) to get $\epsilon^*_i$, then make new $Y^*_i=X_i\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}}+\epsilon^*_i$, then run OLS on the new dataset, $\left(Y^*,X \right)$ to get this replication's $\beta^*_r$.  At last, this replication's draw on $X_{N+1}\left( \beta-\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}} \right)$ is $X_{N+1}\left( \hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}}-\beta^*_r \right)$

Given we are assuming iid $\epsilon$, the natural way to sample from the $\epsilon_{N+1}$ part of the equation is to use the residuals we have from the regression, $\left\{ e^*_1,e^*_2,\ldots,e^*_N \right\}$.  Residuals have different and generally too small variances, so we will want to sample from $\left\{ s_1-\overline{s},s_2-\overline{s},\ldots,s_N-\overline{s} \right\}$, the variance-corrected residuals, where $s_i=e^*_i/\sqrt{(1-h_i)}$ and $h_i$ is the leverage of observation $i$.

And, finally, the algorithm for making a 90% prediction interval for $Y_{N+1}$, given that $X$ is $X_{N+1}$ is:

1. Make the prediction $Y^p_{N+1}=X_{N+1}\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}}$.
2. Make the variance-adjusted residuals,  $\left\{ s_1-\overline{s},s_2-\overline{s},\ldots,s_N-\overline{s}\right\}$, where $s_i=e_i/\sqrt(1-h_{i})$.
3. For replications $r=1,2,\ldots,R$:

   - Draw $N$ times on the adjusted residuals
     to make bootstrap residuals 
     $\left\{\epsilon^*_1,\epsilon^*_2,\ldots,\epsilon^*_N \right\}$
   - Generate bootstrap $Y^*=X\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}}+\epsilon^*$
   - Calculate bootstrap OLS estimator for this replication, 
     $\beta^*_r=\left( X'X \right)^{-1}X'Y^*$
   - Obtain bootstrap residuals from this replication, $e^*_r=Y^*-X\beta^*_r$
   - Calculate bootstrap variance-adjusted residuals from this 
     replication, $s^*-\overline{s^*}$
   - Draw one of the bootstrap variance-adjusted residuals from this
     replication, $\epsilon^*_{N+1,r}$
   - Calculate this replication's draw on 
     $e^p_{N+1}$, $e^{p*}_r=X_{N+1}\left( \hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}}-\beta^*_r
     \right)+\epsilon^*_{N+1,r}$
4. Find $5^{th}$ and $95^{th}$ percentiles of $e^p_{N+1}$, $e^5,e^{95}$
5. 90% prediction interval for $Y_{N+1}$ is
   $\left[Y^p_{N+1}+e^5,Y^p_{N+1}+e^{95} \right]$.

Here is `R` code:

```
# This script gives an example of the procedure to construct a prediction interval
# for a linear regression model using a bootstrap method.  The method is the one
# described in Section 6.3.3 of Davidson and Hinckley (1997),
# _Bootstrap Methods and Their Application_.


#rm(list=ls())
set.seed(12344321)
library(MASS)
library(Hmisc)

# Generate bivariate regression data
x <- runif(n=100,min=0,max=100)
y <- 1 + x + (rexp(n=100,rate=0.25)-4)

my.reg <- lm(y~x)
summary(my.reg)

# Predict y for x=78:
y.p <- coef(my.reg)["(Intercept)"] + coef(my.reg)["x"]*78
y.p

# Create adjusted residuals
leverage <- influence(my.reg)$hat
my.s.resid <- residuals(my.reg)/sqrt(1-leverage)
my.s.resid <- my.s.resid - mean(my.s.resid)


reg <- my.reg
s <- my.s.resid

the.replication <- function(reg,s,x_Np1=0){
  # Make bootstrap residuals
  ep.star <- sample(s,size=length(reg$residuals),replace=TRUE)

  # Make bootstrap Y
  y.star <- fitted(reg)+ep.star

  # Do bootstrap regression
  x <- model.frame(reg)[,2]
  bs.reg <- lm(y.star~x)

  # Create bootstrapped adjusted residuals
  bs.lev <- influence(bs.reg)$hat
  bs.s   <- residuals(bs.reg)/sqrt(1-bs.lev)
  bs.s   <- bs.s - mean(bs.s)

  # Calculate draw on prediction error
  xb.xb <- coef(my.reg)["(Intercept)"] - coef(bs.reg)["(Intercept)"] 
  xb.xb <- xb.xb + (coef(my.reg)["x"] - coef(bs.reg)["x"])*x_Np1
  return(unname(xb.xb + sample(bs.s,size=1)))
}

# Do bootstrap with 10,000 replications
ep.draws <- replicate(n=10000,the.replication(reg=my.reg,s=my.s.resid,x_Np1=78))

# Create prediction interval
y.p+quantile(ep.draws,probs=c(0.05,0.95))

# prediction interval using normal assumption
predict(my.reg,newdata=data.frame(x=78),interval="prediction",level=0.90)


# Quick and dirty Monte Carlo to see which prediction interval is better
# That is, what are the 5th and 95th percentiles of Y_{N+1}
# 
# To do it properly, I guess we would want to do the whole procedure above
# 10,000 times and then see what percentage of the time each prediction 
# interval covered Y_{N+1}

y.np1 <- 1 + 78 + (rexp(n=10000,rate=0.25)-4)
quantile(y.np1,probs=c(0.05,0.95))
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful, detailed explanations. Following these lines, I think that a general technique outside OLS (tree based techniques, nearest neighbour etc.) wont be easily available, right?

Comment: There is this one for random forests: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49750/how-do-i-calculate-prediction-intervals-for-random-forest-predictions?rq=1 which sounds similar.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if you abstract $X\beta$ to $f(X, \theta)$, this technique works for any model.

Comment: How do you generalise the "variance adjusted residuals" - the OLS approach relies on the leverage - is there a leverage calculation for an arbitrary f(X) estimator?

Comment: H = X(XTX)^-1XT (note:T is transpose). The diagonal entries of this matrix are the leverages for each observation. - Applied Regression Modeling, Second Edition (Iain Pardoe).  For assistance with Matrix Multiplication: https://www.real-statistics.com/multiple-regression/multiple-regression-analysis/multiple-regression-analysis-excel/

Answer (score 4):

Consider the much simpler solution than the excelent answer offered by Bill, that following the model based resampling of Sections 6.2.3 and 6.3.3 of Davidson and Hinckley (1997), *Bootstrap Methods and Their Application* consider `X` as fixed by design.

Simply add `sample(resid(fit.b), size = 1)` to the prediction line in STEP 3, this will add the necessary variability to the prediction to account for uncertainty in the irreducible error:

```
# STEP 1: GENERATE DATA
set.seed(34345)

n <- 100 
x <- runif(n)
y <- 1 + 0.2*x + rnorm(n)
data <- data.frame(x, y)

# STEP 2: COMPUTE CLASSIC 95%-PREDICTION INTERVAL
fit <- lm(y ~ x)

# Classic prediction interval based on standard error of forecast
predict(fit, list(x = 0.1), interval = "p")
# -0.6588168 3.093755

# Classic confidence interval based on standard error of estimation
predict(fit, list(x = 0.1), interval = "c")
# 0.893388 1.54155

# STEP 3: NOW BY BOOTSTRAP 95%-PREDICTION INTERVAL
B <- 1000
pred <- numeric(B)
for (i in 1:B) {
  boot <- sample(n, n, replace = TRUE)
  fit.b <- lm(y ~ x, data = data[boot,])
  pred[i] <- predict(fit.b, list(x = 0.1)) + sample(resid(fit.b), size = 1)
}
quantile(pred, c(0.025, 0.975))
# -0.5976346  3.0901755
```

This 95% bootstrap interval matches the 95% prediction interval, and this can be generalized quite easily to other more general models.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This will work for hypothetical situations with homogeneous residual variance.

Comment: I guess that without homogeneity you can always adjust the residuals with the leverage along de lines suggested by Bill. Centering is not necesary, since OLS residuals hace zero mean.

Comment: Agreed, for OLS it is well known how to do it. But this question is actually not on OLS.

Comment: Does this work for ridge or lasso regressions?