# Prediction Intervals for a Two-Part Model?

Tags: regression, prediction-interval

I have fit a two-part model, where the first part is using a logistic regression to model the probability of seeing Y, and the second part is using a Gamma GLM regression with a log link to model the value of Y, conditional on it being positive.

I have then calculated predictions of Y for new values of X by multiplying the probability predicted from the logistic regression, by the value of Y predicted from the Gamma GLM regression for each value of X. How can I go about computing the prediction interval for specific values of X?

I was thinking of using bootstrapping, using the method suggested at the following link. However, I am not sure how I would bake in residual uncertainty over two models.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/501275/360160

Comment: So if you have from logistic regression the probability of "seeing Y" being 0.1 and from glm regression a y-value of e.g. 100, then you would predict y to be 10?

Comment: @frank That is the logic, I am using - yes